# Difference between greater and less than signs?

Tags: geometry, arithmetic

I remain confused by greater than and less than signs, as indicated in this short music video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmFL9AvcR5M&t=1s

Comment: Could you be more specific about your confusion?

Comment: This place is not to promote YouTube videos. Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to relate... To me, knowing the difference between $<$ and $>$ is the same as knowing the difference between $+$ and $\times$, or knowing the difference between $0$ and $1$.  One of the benefits of language and writing in particular is the ability to associate symbols with meanings.  If you are confused about the difference in meaning of the phrases "greater than" and "less than", then we can help.  If you are confused about which symbol, be it $>$ or $<$ is the symbol associated with the concept "greater than"...

Comment: So, are you asking to have it clarified.  Both greater than and less than signs point to the small value.

Answer (score 2):

"$<$" is less than, "$>$" is greater than. I remember these by remembering that the part where the point is is always smaller. So $7>3$ makes sense because the $3$ is next to the point, and is the smaller of the numbers. $7<3$ would be incorrect by the same logic.

Comment: My first grade teacher told me that "The alligator is hungry and always eats the bigger one"

Comment: I never learned the "names" of the signs as they can be turned the other way round, but +1 for the rest

Answer (score 1):

When someone is saying, "Two is greater than one", he/she is saying $2>1$. Think about the game pacman, pacman wants to eat more, so the **GREATER** value ($2$) is where the mouth is pointing to.

I have found more success with "pacman" than with alligators.

Here is the image which portrays what you should be thinking:

[image]

Note: For two numbers $a$ and $b$, with $a$ being the larger number, $a>b$ means the same as $b<a$. If you read it from left to right, the two inequalities mean "$a$ is greater than $b$" and "$b$ is less than $a$".

Answer (score 0):

You put your finger far apart to indicate something is big.  And you pinch your fingers together to indicate something is small.

So the bigger thing is always on the side where the lines are far apart and the smaller thing is always on the side where the lines are pinched together.

They both say the same thing.

$3 < 7$ and $7 > 3$ both say "of the two numbers $7$ and $3$, $7$ is the larger one and $3$ is the smaller one".  Which sign you use indicates what position you placed the numbers in.  The pinch end will always point to the smaller one  and the splayed out end will always indicate where the bigger number is.